# Is it more appropriate to use **feet** here, "the dog has lain at his master's **foot**"?

Tags: word-usage

This [tutorial](https://youtu.be/htZ-uYoMNS8?t=289) gives an example

> the dog has lain at his master's **foot**

Is it more appropriate to use **feet** here?

Comment: The video doesn't give the context, but my guess is that the phrase might describe something like a [tomb effigy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Arundel_Tomb) rather than an actual man and dog. 'Foot' might be used as in 'foot of the bed', to refer to that end of the figure.

Comment: The lecturer said "take the dog by his collar" a few seconds ago, which indicates it's a real dog, and then his master should be a real person, right?

Comment: But if they are just grammar examples, do they have to refer to the same dog?

Comment: Maybe the master has one foot!